# Node request not working when I add proxy

Tags: node.js, http, express, proxy, request

I hit the request using npm Request and get Data. see below and its working fine.

```
const Request = require('request');
   let option = {          
        url:'Request URL',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    };

    Request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log({ error, response, body });
      } else {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    });
```

But when I hit same URL with proxy request.

```
let option = {          
        url:'Request URL',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        proxy: 'Proxy server details',
    };

    Request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log({ error, response, body });
      } else {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    });
```

Then it shows Error like

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403
at ClientRequest.onConnect (/home/admin14/node_projects/bigmuskie/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:166:19)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:475:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: statusCode=403 - it could be the issue of permission to access . try it manually from terminal